# Why is magneto-resistance not possible classically?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hall-effect

Someone recently asked me this question and I don't know why we can't talk about magnetoresistance in the classical picture. As we know that magnetoresistance is the tendency of a material (often ferromagnetic) to change the value of its electrical resistance in an externally-applied magnetic field. I don't understand what is classical or quantum mechanical about this magnetoresistance.

Comment: Ferromagnetism is phenomena that is explained by the alignment of electron spins. Since spin is purely quantum mechanical, it makes sense to talk a ferromagnetism/magnetotesistance from a quantum viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a famous and often-quoted theorem of Bohr and van. Leeuwen, according to which classical physics cannot possibly lead to magnetism, because in pure classical physics the electrons in the material do not interact with an applied magnetic field.

For the proof, check "Introduction to the Theory of Ferromagnetism" by Amikam Aharoni

Click [here](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoth00ahar/page/6/mode/2up) for the proof.